# Assembly reference from ASP.NET App_Code directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, assemblies, reference

I have trouble getting a custom ObjectDataSource for an asp:ListView control to work. I have the class for the DataSource in the App_Code directory of the web application (as required by the asp:ListView control).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Web;
using System.DirectoryServices;

    [DataObject]
    public class UsersDAL
    {
        [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
        public List<User> LoadAll(int startIndex, int maxRows, string sortedBy)
        {
            List<User> users = new List<User>();

            DirectoryEntry entry;

            return users;
        }
    }
```

As soon as I add `using System.DirectoryServices;` the page crashes with this message:
`Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`
Without the usage of *System.DirectoryServices* the page loads without problems.

The reference is there, it is working in classes outside the `App_Code` directory.

Comment: Are you missing an assembly reference? It sounds stupid but check it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect a mix-up between Web Application Project and a Web Site.  Which do you have?

Do you have a reference to System.DirectoryServices in your web.config?  Probably not.  And this is why it's not working.

If you have a Web Application Project, dispense with App_Code.  It is unnecessary, and potentially harmful.  Case in point, your trouble here.

Comment: I suspect you are right. I removed the project and started from Scratch, and now it is working without the App_Code directory. I'm not entirely sure what I did different this time though.